# What determines how many levels a skill receives when it is leveled up?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

When I've leveled up a skill, I have seen it receive one, two or three levels. What determines that number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's random. So we could say the only thing affecting it is your own luck.

Source: Personal experience, [wiki](http://sword-of-the-stars-the-pit.wikia.com/wiki/Skills), official forum (can't find that thread now so now link to it)